# What can I do with Xbox Gold?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

When I unlock achievements on Xbox LIVE, I get rewarded with Gold. Here is an example of Gold giving achievements in Wordament worth 10-20G:

[image: Achievements]

Collectively, from different games, they accumulate on my profile:
[image: Gold]

Where can the Gold be used?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't just Gamerscore?

Comment: @Fluttershy it sure sounds like [Gamerscore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamerscore#Gamerscore). I'd never heard of that before.

Comment: Gold in this case could just mean you have a Gold account? Trying switching it to silver and see :P

Comment: @Samjus it does! I cancelled my subscription and it no longer says Gold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

G just means its a gamerscore. Gamerscore is more for bragging rights.  Xbox just implemented a [rewards program](http://rewards.xbox.com/).

If you have a certain amount of gamerscore you are put into three categories which can be found [here](http://rewards.xbox.com/myrewards/).

**Contender** - 3000-9999 gamescore and you get this is a reward:

```
          •A Special Gift during your birthday month
```

**Champion** - 10000-24999 gamescore and you get this is a reward:

```
          •A Special Gift during your birthday month
          •1% Rebate on your Xbox LIVE Marketplace purchases EVERY MONTH*
```

**Legend** - 25000+ gamescore and you get this is a reward:

```
          •A Special Gift during your birthday month
          •2% Rebate on your Xbox LIVE Marketplace purchases EVERY MONTH*
```

Comment: Nice to see they do have some value other than bragging rights. Signed up!

Comment: My birthday gift was 20 microsoft points. I hope they up that next time haha

Answer (score 2):

I think the gold which you are referring to (example: "swipe those tiles 10G") is in fact something called GamerScore (abbreviated G), you can't really use it for anything besides showing your friends and competitors how accomplished you are at a game or games.  I do know you get some perks on your b-day but that's about as much as i know.  On top of that you can't spend it anywhere, if you had MSP (Microsoft Points) then you could use that at the XBOX Live Marketplace where you can buy games, avatar items, etc.